How can I change the contents of apphosting.yaml per branch?
I'm using Firebase AppHosting to host Next.js. Since there are multiple environments for different branches of the same repository, I would like to switch the contents of apphosting.yaml, which specifies environment variables, for each branch. In this case, is there no choice but to obtain all values ​​from GCP's secrets manager? Also, the only way to separate Cloud Run settings for each environment is to create separate repositories.
The official documentation is below.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-hosting/configure?hl=ja
I've searched a lot but can't seem to find anyone having the same problem.

Hi there, Firebaser here
Update August 25, 2024: We now have official support for multiple environments! You can find more information here https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-hosting/multiple-environments
This should address your use case, take a look and let us know what you think!
